# Android JSON limiting rows

Tags: java, android, json

Currently in my application I get a JSON object with an JSON Array in it. Is it possible to limit the rows (request header?) before data is returned from the server to client ?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Not enough information. What's running on the server?

Comment: It's an API I am using from blizzard but some calls give to much data.

Comment: Does the API documentation say there's a way to limit the number of rows returned?

Comment: No , function is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general way to limit the amount of data returned in an HTTP request.

If your API specifies a way to do it (such as a request header) then use that. If not, there is no way to prevent the server from sending more data than you want.